# Mark locations on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, maps

I'm fairly new to coding, and am experimenting on creating my own personal project. I was able to get a simple map up and running.

How would I create just for example all of the breweries in your area. Would I need to access an API and then create a marker for each one? OR just create a search bar within the map and Google "breweries"?

```
 <div id="container">

        <div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
      key="KEYHERE"&callback=myMap"> 
       </script>

 </div>


function myMap() {
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(39.742043,-104.991531)
var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('googleMap');
var mapOptions = {center: myCenter, zoom: 9};
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:myCenter});
marker.setMap(map);

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: "Denver" });
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
}
```

If you have websites with examples or examples yourselves to help me out to learn I'd greatly appreciate it. I just don't know how it works. Thanks

Comment: `key="KEYHERE"` ... I hope you don't put the KEY in quotes like that

Comment: It's clearly a placeholder..however the src = is a link. So, technically the link and Key are in quotes.

Comment: Just making sure - yes, the whole url is in quotes - I must admit I didn't read the question fully, didn't realise you posted *working code*

Answer (score 1):

i will share link which gives guidelines using this you create API key and just copy in the following script,

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <style>
          #map {
            height: 400px;  
            width: 100%;  
           }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
        <!--The div element for the map -->
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
    // Initialize and add the map
    function initMap() {

      var uluru = {lat: -104.991531, lng: 39.742043};

      var map = new google.maps.Map(
          document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: uluru});
      // The marker, positioned at your location 
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
    }
        </script>
        <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
 key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Follow the following link,

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map